# IO Exception in Audio Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play audio through streaming in Media Player.

I used the sample project source code from http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/, but I'm getting a IO exception for media player saying that there is no media player to play when I debug. I am getting the file from a buffer, but there is a problem in Media Player telling me that there is no media player to play the file.

My code is

```
 package com.pocketjourney.media;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    /**
     * MediaPlayer does not yet support streaming from external URLs so this class provides a pseudo-streaming function
     * by downloading the content incrementally & playing as soon as we get enough audio in our temporary storage.
     */
    public class StreamingMediaPlayer {

        private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER =  96*10/8;//assume 96kbps*10secs/8bits per byte

        private TextView textStreamed;

        private ImageButton playButton;

        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        //  Track for display by progressBar
        private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;
        private int totalKbRead = 0;

        // Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        private MediaPlayer     mediaPlayer;

        private File downloadingMediaFile; 

        private boolean isInterrupted;

        private Context context;

        private int counter = 0;

        public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context,TextView textStreamed, ImageButton playButton, Button  streamButton,ProgressBar    progressBar) 
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
            this.playButton = playButton;
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
        }

        /**  
         * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
         */  
        public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long  mediaLengthInKb, long   mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException {

            this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
            this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {   
                public void run() {   
                    try {   
                        downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=" + mediaUrl, e);
                        return;
                    }   
                }   
            };   
            new Thread(r).start();
        }

        /**  
         * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the setDataSource  
         * for that local file
         */  
        public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

            URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
            cn.connect();   
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
            }

            downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia_" + (counter++) + ".dat");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
            byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
            int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
            do {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);   
                if (numread <= 0)   
                    break;   
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                totalBytesRead += numread;
                incrementalBytesRead += numread;
                totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

                testMediaBuffer();
                fireDataLoadUpdate();
            } while (validateNotInterrupted());   

            stream.close();
            if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
                fireDataFullyLoaded();
            }
        }  

        private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {
            if (isInterrupted) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    //mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        /**
         * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
         * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
         */  
        private void  testMediaBuffer() {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                        if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                            try {
                                startMediaPlayer();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);               
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ( mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 ){ 
                        //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                        //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                        //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                        transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.post(updater);
        }

        private void startMediaPlayer() {
            try {   
                File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");
                moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

                Log.e("Player",bufferedFile.length()+"");
                Log.e("Player",bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());


                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
// ham getting error here
                mediaPlayer.prepare();



                fireDataPreloadComplete();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlaer.", e);
                return;
            }   
        }

        /**
         * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
         * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
         */  
        private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
            try {
                // First determine if we need to restart the player after transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
                boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.pause();

                File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");
                //FileUtils.copyFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioSystem.STREAM_MUSIC);

                       mediaPlayer.prepare();  
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

                //  Restart if at end of prior beuffered content or mediaPlayer was previously playing.  
                //  NOTE:  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
                if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);                  
            }

        }

        private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textStreamed.setText((CharSequence) (totalKbRead + " Kb read"));
                    float loadProgress = ((float)totalKbRead/(float)mediaLengthInKb);
                    progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int)(loadProgress*100));
                }
            };
            handler.post(updater);
        }

        /**
         * We have preloaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so update the buttons & progress meters.
         */
        private void fireDataPreloadComplete() {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    playButton.setEnabled(true);
                    //streamButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            };
            handler.post(updater);
        }

        private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
            Runnable updater = new Runnable() { 
                public void run() {
                    transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                    textStreamed.setText((CharSequence) ("Audio full loaded: " + totalKbRead + " Kb read"));
                }
            };
            handler.post(updater);
        }

        public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
            return mediaPlayer;
        }

        public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
            float progress = (((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000)/(float)mediaLengthInSeconds);
            progressBar.setProgress((int)(progress*100));

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
            }
        }    

        public void interrupt() {
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            isInterrupted = true;
            validateNotInterrupted();
        }

        public void moveFile(File   oldLocation, File   newLocation)
        throws IOException {

            if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
                BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
                BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
                try {
                    byte[]  buff = new byte[8192];
                    int numChars;
                    while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                        writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
                    }
                } catch( IOException ex ) {
                    throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if ( reader != null ){
                            writer.close();
                            reader.close();
                        }
                    } catch( IOException ex ){
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() ); 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
            }
        }
    }
```